# SAS FIND() - Finding the position of two consecutive capital letters

Tags: sas, text-parsing

Fish tailing off a previous question/answer in looking for the position of any capital letter in a string. While I can ID the scenario above with the previous provided answer:

```
DATA TEST;
SET SAMPLE;
_endpos= FINDC(TXT,,'u');
ID = substr(TXT,1,_endpos-1);
RUN;
```

How would I go about finding conditions where there are two consecutive capital letters in a row? Not sure how to the provide the information to represent two consecutive occurrences of the 'u' option here....

```
DATA TEST;
SET SAMPLE;
_endpos= FINDC(TXT,__,'u');
ID = substr(TXT,1,_endpos-1);
RUN;
```

or

```
DATA TEST;
SET SAMPLE;
_endpos= FINDC(TXT,  ,'u');
ID = substr(TXT,1,_endpos-1);
RUN;
```

Comment: Look at regex functions instead of native SAS functions. If your new to them use a builder to help get the code correct. http://regexr.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the delimiters to include white space and punctuation.

```
data _2upcase;
   input string $50.;
   do c=1 by 1 until(l eq 2 or p eq 0);
      call scan(strip(string),c,p,l,,'ldsp');
      end;
   length _2upcase $2;
   _2upcase = substrn(string,p,l);
   cards;
nndkd11UUndkdLLL
kdnakaliueoina
nnnlllLLLlllLLlll
thisISa2DIgit
this IS silly
this.IS.silly
;;;;
   run;
```

Comment: This is somewhat what I need, but seems your parsing out two of the SAME capital letters consecutively...as I need to find the position of where there are two consecutive uppercase characters in which the letters are not the same. So really...looking for the starting position of Any two consecutive alpha characters that are not necessarily always the same letter. Sorry for the unclear question.

Comment: @SMW apparently you didn't test it.  I added two delimiter classes.  The program finds strings that are length 2 and delimited by lowercase, digits, white space or punctuation.

Comment: No...I did not test...but eager to get back in office. Apologies...and it seems that you DO understood my intent...once I test I will throw you some +1 and the old check mark! Question...I explored Reezas suggestion of a regular expression ...is this the preferred method to handle parsing over data step processing (perl is a jungle for me!)...